# How do I convert a daynumber (day nr 331) into yyyymmdd in PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, date, plsql, numbers

If I know the number of the day is 331 within the year, how do I convert it into yyyymmdd in PL/SQL?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To convert to a DATE:

```
to_date(331, 'DDD')
```

You can then format that date if required using TO_CHAR.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @datetime2 datetime2 = '2007-01-01 13:10:10.1111111'
SELECT 'day',DATEADD(day,331,@datetime2)
```

Comment: That is SQL Server syntax, not Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be something like this.

```
select to_char(trunc(sysdate, 'YY') + 331, 'YYYYMMDD') as day from dual
```